# How to resolve ~/ aka application relative url in a middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm struggling to redirect a user to the correct location in an ASP.NET Core middleware.

What I'm trying to archieve is an application relative redirect, so if my app runs as https://www.example.com/app any link generated should be rooted there.

E.g. ~/path should resolve to /app/path.

I tried using UrlHelperFactory, but that's MVC and needs an ActionContext, which does not exist inside a middleware.

Heres a code sample of my middleware:

```
app.Map(pathMatch, appMap =>
{
    // [... more code ...]

    appMap.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var nextUrl = context.Request.Query["nextUrl"];
        var applicationBase = context.Request.PathBase;

        if (nextUrl == StringValues.Empty || !UrlUtil.IsLocalUrl(nextUrl[0]))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(applicationBase);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(applicationBase.Add(nextUrl[0]));
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```

Comment: The `~` is not a standard path component. Razor and things like `UrlHelper` recognizes this as meaning "my application's base path" and substitutes accordingly, but you can't use it in scenarios like this. What is wrong with your current solution of using `PathBase`?

Comment: PathBase unfortunately includes the pathMatch of the app.Map-call

Comment: Kind of stupid of me, to not include the code, where ~ was still replaced, but the gist is the same...

Comment: Well, the issue is that there's not really a reliable way to get at this info. ASP.NET could provide this to you because it had one and only one predictable hosting model: IIS. ASP.NET Core can deployed all sorts of different ways, including behind load-balancers, reverse-proxies, application gateways, and all sorts of other things that would make the public facing URL potentially entirely different from how the app is actually running and configured.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue using nginx as a reverse proxy for an application via a virtual path. The only way to compensate was to manually set `PathBase` via middleware, so that the app could generate URLs correctly (Scheme, authority, etc. come via `X-Forwarded` headers. Not sure why there's no way to specify a path in this way.)